# checked radio option slide from one to another(vanilla js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 options to choose and require to achieve such look(attached screenshot). My first idea was to use radio inputs. But I have reached a problem, of how to make the selection look the same as design. Could someone please give at leaast a clue, of how that could be done?

[image]

Here is the code snippet:

```css
.container {
    max-width: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.select-plan {
    text-align: center;
}

.spacer {
    width: 100%;
}

.spacer-gap--16 {
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.select-plan__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.select-plan__radio, .select-plan__input {
    display: block;
}

.dimensional-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <form class="select-plan" action="">
            <div class="select-plan__container">
                <div class="dimensional-container">
                    <input class="select-plan__radio" type="radio" name="select-month" value="one-month" id="select-month">
                    <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-month">1 month</label>
                </div>
                <div class="dimensional-container">
                    <input class="select-plan__radio" type="radio" name="select-month" value="three-months" id="select-three-month" checked>
                    <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-three-month">3 month</label>
                </div>
                <div class="dimensional-container">
                    <input class="select-plan__radio" type="radio" name="select-month" value="twelve-months" id="select-twelve-month">
                    <label class="select-plan__label" for="select-twelve-month">12 month</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer spacer-gap--16"></div>
            <button class="select-plan__submit" type="submit">Try now</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should try searching "range sliders". once you implement those, you can later on work on your visuals.

Comment: @NikosGkogkopoulos thanks, that's a really good option. Will make a research on that right now. Is it possible to somehow check the current value of range slider if user choose something?

Comment: take a look at this if you didn't already solve it. https://codepen.io/t0m_asht0n/pen/bgXMYx

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to hide your inputs and have the labels positioned how they are in the picture. Then you can have a div slide along. That way when you click the label you can move the div with javascript.